# Did I just destroy my kitchen floor tiles?

Tags: kitchens, tile, sealant

I have owned this house less than a week and today got to scrubbing the kitchen floor with a tile brush and multipurpose cleaner. Suddenly large chunks of clear film start coming off the tiles. Help! What have I done?! Is this varnish? Sealer? Have I ruined my tiles? (Although, they kinda look better now they aren’t so shiny).

Any pointers gratefully received!!!

[image: The tiles where the film has come off]

[image: The gross film that peeled off]

Comment: It looks like a protective plastic film(like on TV screens) that was not removed.  Varnish and sealers I would expect to be harder to remove(sanding, grinding if they were decent).  Installers might not have known, but should have read the instructions(which most of us do not after the first time).  It is strange to me that tile has a film(just a simple tile installer once or twice).

Comment: It could just be an attempt at a water proof coating with unfit for purpose product. I have never seen films on tiles  even on expensive Italian ones.

Comment: @RohitGupta  I could see a film for protection from scratches during shipping, but odd.

Comment: How old is the house or tile installation?  You still might need a sealer for the tiles, since the installers did not use one.  Check with the builder if a new/er house(five years).